# 18GB of Other storage

Tags: macos, storage, games

I bought the game Wargame: European Escalation a while back off Steam and went to uninstall it today. I deleted it, but now my storage is filled with  18GB of "Other". I am on El Capitan version 10.11.1. How do I remove this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried emptying the trash?

Comment: Try restarting your computer in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262), restart normally, then check the usage. You can read about what "Other" space is comprised of on your storage device [at this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262).

Comment: Since the game is from Steam, it might be left over game files stored within the /Library/Application Support
After all, *deleting* the app doesn't delete it's data

Comment: Yes, emptying the trash was the first thing I did. After restarting in safe mode and then normally, it removed 4GB of other. I went through the Application Support and deleted some files of older games I deleted, I couldn't find any files files for the game I recently deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a scan of your hard drive with the tool [Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net). With that (a free tool), you can easily see what exact files and data are eating up space, as well as where they are in your file tree. Then, it'll be easy to root out and delete what you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

“Other” storage simply includes everything that doesn’t fit into pre-existing categories. This includes browser cache, cached email messages & attachments, iTunes backups, notes, voice memos, call history, etc.

Here i found an article explained in detail what's is "Other" on iPhone, and how to clear up "Other", you should have a look: [mysterious “Other” on iPhone](https://www.imyfone.com/iphone-space-saver/how-to-clear-other-on-iphone/).

Comment: The question pertains to OS X, not iOS.